# R using RJDBC not writing data to Hive table

Tags: r, hive, rjdbc

RJDBC connecting to Hive fine and also reading the data from Hive. But it is not writing data to Hive using --> dbWriteTable.

see below-

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8g")
library(DBI)
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)

cp <- c(list.files("/tmp/R_hive_libs/cloudera_hive_jars", pattern = "[.]jar", full.names=TRUE, recursive=TRUE),list.files("/tmp/R_hive_libs/R_hadoop_libs", pattern = "[.]jar", full.names=TRUE, recursive=TRUE),list.files("/tmp/R_hive_libs/R_hadoop_libs/lib", pattern = "[.]jar", full.names=TRUE, recursive=TRUE), recursive=TRUE)

drv <- JDBC(driverClass = "com.cloudera.hive.jdbc4.HS2Driver", classPath=cp)
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:hive2://XXXXXX:10000/default", "user", "password")
show_databases <- dbGetQuery(conn, "show databases")
List_of_Tables <- dbListTables(conn)

data1 <- dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from XXX.xxx limit 10000")
data_to_write_back_to_hive <- data.frame(aggregate(data1$xxx.xxx, by=list(Month=data1$xxx.cmp_created_timestamp_month), FUN=sum))
data_to_write_back_to_hive[[2]] <-c(10,20)
colnames(data_to_write_back_to_hive) <- c("Month", "Energy")
dbWriteTable(conn, "xxxx.checking",data_to_write_back_to_hive)
```

How to write data back to hive? it is giving below error-

> **Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :   execute JDBC update query failed in dbSendUpdate ([Simba]HiveJDBCDriver ERROR
>   processing query/statement. Error Code: 40000, SQL state:
>   TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS,
>   infoMessages:[*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Error
>   while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:36 mismatched
>   input 'PRECISION' expecting ) near 'DOUBLE' in create table
>   statement:28:27,**
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:toSQLException:Operation.java:326,
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:prepare:SQLOperation.java:102,
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:runInternal:SQLOperation.java:171,
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:run:Operation.java:268,
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:executeStatementInternal:HiveSessionImpl.java:410,
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:executeStatement:HiveSessionImpl.java:391,
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor56:invoke::-1,
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMeth

Comment: where you able to finf some work around for this? PRECISION key word is not supported in version less than hive 2.0

Answer (score 0):

This question comes up [a fair bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28211999/r-using-rjdbc-write-table-to-hive/28635225#28635225).  I think the short answer is that you can't do what you want at present.  The DBI/JDBC drivers don't metaprogram syntactically correct HiveQL.

Comment: im guessing this is due to hive version? hive 2.0+ might work with this

Comment: Possible, HIVE and EMR have had plenty of updates since my post. Perhaps someone will update